# How To Fit UITableView in the screen with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to fill the screen with a TableView. I've tried pinning 4 edges but it broke when I view it in different devices (iPad Pro, iPhone SE, landscape and portrait orientation). The TableView is messed up for some reasons. It shouldn't be this hard to fill that in. Did I messed up some settings in my Xcode?

[image: Adding the Constraint]

[image: The layout misalign in landscape mode]

[image: Viewing in iPad]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ran the application on a real device you'll find it as you expect it to be.

And if you opened another file then came back to storyboard you'll find the preview as expected too, I think it's a bug in the UI Builder.

Note: I'm using Xcode Version 8.3.2.